# export var to routes files expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm completely new to nodejs + expressjs comming from php and I'm getting trouble how to export/include a var to my routes/users.js file.

on app.js I have:

```
//database connection
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'dbNodeExpress'
});
```

... some code

`var user = require('./routes/user');`  //here I include my routes/files (I dont know if it's right to include the routes here - for learning purposes it works for now)

... more code until starts the server

On my /routes/user.js

```
app = require('../app');
 //var mysql = require('mysql');
 var baseUrl = app.get('baseUrl');

app.get('/users_mysql', function(req, res){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, users){
    res.json(users);
  });
});
```

and I get the express error: 500 ReferenceError: connection is not defined

The connection works because if I move the content from users.js to app.js I can query the database.

My questions is how to inject the var connection to be used on routes/users.js

Any help / hint to understand this is very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at module.exports in Nodejs. Also have a look at this https://github.com/focusaurus/express_code_structure/blob/master/app/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this. A couple solutions might be:

1. Create a resources.js file that creates and exports the connection. Then require() resources.js in every source file where you need it.
2. Pass the connection to your user route file. Something like this:

```js
// app.js
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'dbNodeExpress'
});
require('./routes/user')(connection);


// routes/user.js
module.exports = function(connection) {
  app.get('/users_mysql', function(req, res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, users){
      res.json(users);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

create a database connector javascript file. as like database_connector.js
and require it  when ever you want to have the connection pooled or the connection class availabel to your models. **tip** : you can also export config files like below or use barely values.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var config = require("./config");

function Connection() {
    this.pool = null;

    this.init = function() {
        this.pool = mysql.createPool({
            connectionLimit: config.poolSize,
            host: config.host,
            user: config.user,
            password: config.password,
            database: config.database,
            debug:config.debug,
        });
    };

    this.acquire = function(callback) {
        this.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            callback(err, connection);
        });
    };
    console.log("connection"+this.pool);
}

module.exports = new Connection();
```