# Node.js splitting multiple file and use same db connection

Tags: node.js

My node.js is getting really big. I really need to split it into multiple files for easy maintenance. The problem is i do not know how to use the same mongodb connection.

For example, my main.js contain the following

```
var mongodb = require(config.app.module_root_path + 'mongodb');
var db;

mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://test:test@127.0.0.1:27272/test', function(err, database) {

    if(err || database == null) {

        throw err;

    } else {

        db = database;

        db.collection('usertest').ensureIndex({email:1}, {unique:true}, function(err, indexName) {

            if(err) {

                logger.warn(err.message);

            }

        });

        logger.info('Mongodb listening at 27233');

        restful_express.listen(process.env.PORT || 7878, function() {

            logger.info('ExpressJs listening at 7878');

        });

    }

});
```

and userCRUD.js contain

```
restful_express.get('/allUser', function(req, res) {

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");  
  res.type('json'); // set content-type

  db.collection('usertest').find({}, {first_name:1, last_name:1}).toArray(function(err, result) {

     if(!err) {

        res.send({users:result, err:false});

     } 

  });

});
```

how do I pass the var, db to userCRUD.js to use?

reagrds,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23098092/2050455) for a general idea (although in your case it would be a MongoDB connection instead of a MySQL connection).

Comment: hi there, if I also need to use the same like

var check = require('validator').check, sanitize = require('validator').sanitize;

do I also pass in as a parameter like

require('./routes/user')(connection, check, sanitize);

Comment: You could, but since those probably aren't values that have to be instantiated, you could just require() those validator methods inside the route file to keep things sane when you add more of those kinds of dependencies.